# Using React-file-viewer

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use React-file-viewer. Npm tutorial is here 
But I have an error in the console : **"you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"**
This is my code :

```
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer';
import { CustomErrorComponent } from 'custom-error';
const file = 'http://example.com/image.png'
const type = 'png'


 onError = (e) => {
    logger.logError(e, 'error in file-viewer');
 }

 <FileViewer
 fileType={type}
 filePath={file}
 errorComponent={CustomErrorComponent}
 onError={this.onError}/>
```

I specify, i have babel-preset-es2015 and i use it

How can I do ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to include babel in webpack config as

```
loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }]
```

As you are using

```
onError = (e) => {
    logger.logError(e, 'error in file-viewer');
 }
```

which is es6 syntax.To make it browser compatible you have to add

```
{test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']}
```

Comment: can you post webpack config also?

Comment: you are using es6 function so you have to add `{test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']}` also

Comment: thank you for your help, however if i add this line in my webpack, app crash and not build :( . In the console, i have "path is not defined"
Must I import or define "path" ? And how ?

Comment: use only { test: /\.js?$/, loaders: ['babel'] } for your case

Comment: The app build, but I have the same error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type""

Answer (score 1):

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            // .ts(x) files should first pass through the Typescript loader, and then through babel
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['babel', 'ts-loader'] },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]-[hash:base64:5]', 'postcss-loader', 'sass'] },
            { test: /\.(png|svg|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, loaders: [ 'url-loader', 'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug'] },
            { test: /\.(eot|woff|ttf|woff2)$/, loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]" }


        ]
    }
```

Comment: does adding this fixed your problem? Please add more details on your answer so other can get help form this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the following presets and plugins, as listed in `node-modules/react-file-viewer/.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-object-super",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Assuming you already have the `react` and `es2015` in your project, the `npm` command will be:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 \
    babel-plugin-transform-class-properties \
    babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes \
    babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super \
    babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import logger from Logging library,
something like this:

```
import logger from 'logging-Lib';
```

see more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the file using require.

```
// import FileViewer from "react-file-viewer";
const FileViewer = require('react-file-viewer');
```

After that if you are getting any error like Module not found: Can't resolve 'console'. you can run

```
npm install console
```