# How integrate a viewer doc for react or node js

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a docx and pdf viewer in my react app.

Do you know a free viewer who enables to display docx and pdf document in React.js or Node.js ?

I tested react-file-viewer, but i have this error :

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any docx or pdf viewer as they don't require you to access or edit the dom after it's published. You would just create a react component to wrap the content in for easy manipulation.

Comment: No. I tested react file viewer, and it not build, i have an error on the webpack config

Comment: You will need to use something like browserify and babel to use JSX and es6 syntax.

Comment: I'm using already babel with webpack, and in my app i'm using also jsx, and it works. I've just this problem with the module react-file-viewer, but it not build.

Comment: It's your build environment not the plugin, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515802/using-react-file-viewer